# Unable to change with of final sprite using Gulp Spritesmith

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using [Gulp Spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp.spritesmith) to generate a massive long sprite, to make a scrolling animation effect.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-animate-a-coffee-drinking-sprite-with-scrollmagic--cms-24795). And in that tutorial there's this sass-function, that iterates through the images:

```
@for $i from 1 through $frame-count {
  .frame#{$i} {
    background-position: -(($i * $offset-val) * 2) + px 50%;
  }
}
```

I was going to do the same thing, only vertically, so:

```
@for $i from 1 through $frame-count {
  .frame#{$i} {
    background-position: 0px -(($i * $offset-val) * 2) + px;
  }
}
```

But regardless of what I do, then my output sprite is using the `binary-tree`-algorithm to make the sprites.

So if I have 16 images, then the sprite looks like this:

```
1  2  7  13
3  4  8  14
5  6  9  15
10 11 12 16
```

And I would like them to be like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
...
...
```

Here's my core Gulp Spritesmith file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');

gulp.task('default');

gulp.task('sprite', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('images/*.jpg')
  .pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.jpg',
    cssName: 'sprite.css',
    algorithm: 'top-down'
  }));
  spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest('img'));
  spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

I've fiddled around with these three lines for the past hour:

```
  .pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.jpg',
    cssName: 'sprite.css',
  }));
```

... and regardless of what I do, - then I can't get the output files to change (at all!). Not even the name, replacing `cssName: 'sprite.css',` with `cssName: 'foobar.css',`!

What am I missing?

Comment: is it possible to share the full/partial code. Because I tried with the code it is working fine for printing from top to bottom algorithm.

Comment: @kavinraj ... I love you! I had fiddled around with this for SOOO long, and had lost hope. But after you wrote, then I regained hope, - deleted my node_modules, my package.json and started from `npm init --y` and tried again, and now it's working! I think it must have been something in my package.json-file that was off, but I'm not sure. You deserve the bounty. Can I get you to roughly describe how you made it work (in case someone else finds themselves in the same problem). Then I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to make the sprint image from top to bottom approach using [spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spritesmith) or [gulp.spritesmith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp.spritesmith)

where sprite image has 4 images of tile blockm, like below image and so on

[image]

**Sample code :**

*gulpfile.js*

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');

gulp.task('sprite', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('app/images/*.jpg').pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'doodle-sprite.jpg',
    cssName: 'sprite.scss',
    algorithmOpts: {
      sort: false
    },
    algorithm: 'top-down',
  }));
  return spriteData.pipe(gulp.dest('app/images/'));
});
```

---

***my outcome for sprite.scss***

```
@mixin sprite-width($sprite) {
  width: nth($sprite, 5);
}

@mixin sprite-height($sprite) {
  height: nth($sprite, 6);
}

@mixin sprite-position($sprite) {
  $sprite-offset-x: nth($sprite, 3);
  $sprite-offset-y: nth($sprite, 4);
  background-position: $sprite-offset-x  $sprite-offset-y;
}

@mixin sprite-image($sprite) {
  $sprite-image: nth($sprite, 9);
  background-image: url(#{$sprite-image});
}

@mixin sprite($sprite) {
  @include sprite-image($sprite);
  @include sprite-position($sprite);
  @include sprite-width($sprite);
  @include sprite-height($sprite);
}

// The `sprites` mixin generates identical output to the CSS template
//   but can be overridden inside of SCSS
//
// @include sprites($spritesheet-sprites);
@mixin sprites($sprites) {
  @each $sprite in $sprites {
    $sprite-name: nth($sprite, 10);
    .#{$sprite-name} {
      @include sprite($sprite);
    }
  }
}
```

***out come image***

[image]